# Android: make a folder on external memory private or protected

Tags: android, memory, directory, external, private

I want to make a folder on the external memory (could be on SD card) private or protected so that only my application/process can have access to that folder.

Can I do this? if so please let me know?

my requirement:
I can use android's internal memory to store my app's files/data, but that may decrease the phone's internal memory (that can cause problems like not having enough space for other apps to install, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Data on external storage **cannot** be private. It is world-readable and can be changed by the user if they enable USB mass storage.

Quoted from developer.android.com:

> Every Android-compatible device supports a shared "external storage" that you can use to save files. This can be a removable storage media (such as an SD card) or an internal (non-removable) storage. Files saved to the external storage are world-readable and can be modified by the user when they enable USB mass storage to transfer files on a computer.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot.You can zip the folder and store in as pass-worded zip file.

Comment: wowa! Super kool, Sunil how can we do that? can you please share some info on that

Answer (score 0):

Since API 9 you have for this purpose the

[File.setWritable(boolean, boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#setWritable%28boolean,%20boolean%29)

and also for the read/exec operation. take a look to the link

Comment: Thanks, but I have to support from API 7 onwards.

Comment: I have one solution here -- if we can create a folder on the external memory with name begining with "." then that folder can't be visible to the user (ex: .myAppPrivateFolder), then that satisfies my requirement. what say!!!

Comment: users can not see the folder, but the folder still exists... imho it is not a solution.. but it seems there is no solution to set permissions to folder since api 9.. so try to hide the folder and hope for the best :)

Comment: _If the user does not have permission to change the access permissions of this abstract pathname the operation will fail._ Which only is the case for self-created files.

Comment: @OneWorld that's what the documentation states. Is there anything wrong ?

Comment: Seems not to be an useful solution. Whatever operation I try on my dir I made at "/storage/emulated/0/mypriv3", I always get `libcore.io.ErrnoException: chmod failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)`. I tried `File#setReadOnly()`, `File#setWritable(false)`, `File#setWritable(false, false)`, `file.setExecutable(false)` So my assumption is, no app has the right to change permissions without root, even if the folder was created by the app itself

Comment: was that file created by your app ?

Answer (score 0):

quote from android docs:

> `public abstract File getExternalFilesDir (String type)`
>
> Since: API Level 8 Returns the absolute path to the directory on the
> external filesystem (that is somewhere on
> Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()) where the application can
> place persistent files it owns.
>
> These files are private to the
> applications, and not typically visible to the user as media. This is
> like getFilesDir() in that these files will be deleted when the
> application is uninstalled[...]

Source: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29)

So basically you will get a private (sorta) folder in your SD card.

Use this in combination with Blackbelt's answer for better effects.

Comment: You missed an important fact from the docs: _There is no security enforced with these files. For example, any application holding WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE can write to these files._